# Не работает анимация при наследовании компонента

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

Создаю UserDataGrid : DataGrid, на него вешаю стили, анимацию.
Стили работают, а вот анимация нет.
Есть Storyboard, который запускается когда загружается элемент. Анимацию тестировал для DataGrid, там все работает. Но стоит мне эту анимацию повесить на UserDataGrid, то анимация не воспроизводится. Не понимаю где копать.
Вот стиль

```
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsSource"
                     Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Template"
                        Value="{StaticResource WaitControlTemplate}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

А вот сама анимация

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="WaitControlTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrush}">
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Width="24"
                        Height="24"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Canvas.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="spinner"
                                    x:Name="spinner"
                                    BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Rectangle01"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"
                                                      Value="1" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000"
                                                      Value="0.5" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000"
                                                      Value="0.25" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000"
                                                      Value="0.2" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              ...
                        </Storyboard>
                    </Canvas.Resources>
                    <Canvas.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource spinner}" />
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Canvas.Triggers>
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                          Height="24"
                          Width="24" />
                    <Canvas Height="24"
                            Width="24" Visibility="Visible">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle01"
                                   Fill="Gray"
                                   Height="5"
                                   Width="2"
                                   Canvas.Left="11"
                                   Canvas.Top="2"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Opacity="0.2" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle02"
                                   Fill="Gray"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Height="5"
                                   Width="2"
                                   Canvas.Left="11"
                                   Canvas.Top="2"
                                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                   Opacity="0.2">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform />
                                    <SkewTransform />
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="30" />
                                    <TranslateTransform X="3.7499999999999996"
                                                        Y="1.00480947161671" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle03"
                                   Fill="Gray"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Height="5"
                                   Width="2"
                                   Canvas.Left="11"
                                   Canvas.Top="2"
                                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                   UseLayoutRounding="False"
                                   Opacity="0.2">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform />
                                    <SkewTransform />
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="60" />
                                    <TranslateTransform X="6.49519052838329"
                                                        Y="3.7500000271702154" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle04"
                                   Fill="Gray"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Height="5"
                                   Width="2"
                                   Canvas.Left="11"
                                   Canvas.Top="2"
                                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                   UseLayoutRounding="False"
                                   Opacity="0.2">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform />
                                    <SkewTransform />
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                                    <TranslateTransform X="7.5000000920390741"
                                                        Y="7.5" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle05"
                                   Fill="Gray"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Height="5"
                                   Width="2"
                                   Canvas.Left="11"
                                   Canvas.Top="2"
                                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                   UseLayoutRounding="False"
                                   Opacity="0.2">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform />
                                    <SkewTransform />
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="120" />
                                    <TranslateTransform X="6.49519052838329"
                                                        Y="11.25" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle06"
                                   Fill="Gray"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Height="5"
                                   Width="2"
                                   Canvas.Left="11"
                                   Canvas.Top="2"
                                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                   UseLayoutRounding="False"
                                   Opacity="0.2">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform />
                                    <SkewTransform />
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="150" />
                                    <TranslateTransform X="3.7500000920390728"
                                                        Y="13.995190528383292" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle07"
                                   Fill="Gray"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Height="5"
                                   Width="2"
                                   Canvas.Left="11"
                                   Canvas.Top="17"
                                   Opacity="0.2" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle08"
                                   Fill="Gray"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Height="5"
                                   Width="2"
                                   Canvas.Left="11"
                                   Canvas.Top="17"
                                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                   Opacity="0.2">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform />
                                    <SkewTransform />
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="30" />
                                    <TranslateTransform X="-3.7499999999999996"
                                                        Y="-1.00480947161671" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle09"
                                   Fill="Gray"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Height="5"
                                   Width="2"
                                   Canvas.Left="11"
                                   Canvas.Top="17"
                                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                   UseLayoutRounding="False"
                                   Opacity="0.2">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform />
                                    <SkewTransform />
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="60" />
                                    <TranslateTransform X="-6.49519052838329"
                                                        Y="-3.7500000271702154" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle10"
                                   Fill="Gray"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Height="5"
                                   Width="2"
                                   Canvas.Left="11"
                                   Canvas.Top="17"
                                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                   UseLayoutRounding="False"
                                   Opacity="0.2">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform />
                                    <SkewTransform />
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                                    <TranslateTransform X="-7.5000000920390741"
                                                        Y="-7.5" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle11"
                                   Fill="Gray"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Height="5"
                                   Width="2"
                                   Canvas.Left="11"
                                   Canvas.Top="17"
                                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                   UseLayoutRounding="False"
                                   Opacity="0.2">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform />
                                    <SkewTransform />
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="120" />
                                    <TranslateTransform X="-6.49519052838329"
                                                        Y="-11.25" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle12"
                                   Fill="Gray"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Height="5"
                                   Width="2"
                                   Canvas.Left="11"
                                   Canvas.Top="17"
                                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                   UseLayoutRounding="False"
                                   Opacity="0.2">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform />
                                    <SkewTransform />
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="150" />
                                    <TranslateTransform X="-3.7500000920390728"
                                                        Y="-13.995190528383292" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Canvas>
                </Canvas>
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Text="Ждите, идет загрузка данных"
                           FontSize="16" />
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Вынесите `EventTrigger` в стиль `Style.Triggers`

Comment: Проблема не в наследовании, а в ренедере. Когда компонент рендерится, анимация приостанавливается.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232917/wpf-animation-freezes-even-if-i-use-new-thread